# How to preserve javascript object state when the same file is linked from two different jsps?

Tags: javascript, iframe, frames

I have two iframes in a page who's content is formed from 2 different jsps. I have linked a js file in both jsps, and calling different functions that have a common object that I'm setting in the first call to the function.

common js file catalogHL.js:

```
var viewer;

function subscribe(curViewer, status) {


    viewer = curViewer;

    //does something after this. 

}


 function highlight(row, flag) {

/*
 code
*/

subscribe(viewer, false);


/*
 code
*/
}
```

in jsp1 :

```
 window.top.document.addEventListener('someEvent', function (e) {   
 if(viewer && subscribe)
    subscribe(viewer, true);
 }, false);
```

I call subscribe in catalogHL.js and set the viewer variable.

now in jsp2, I have a javascript that calls a method in catalogHL -highlight() that uses viewer.

```
function freeze() {
try {

     if(selectCallBack && selectHandler && selectHandler.length > 0) {

         highlight(strID,true);
     }
} catch(e){
}

}
```

but viewer variable in undefined at this point.

From what I understand since they belong to two different iframes, the state is not preserved.

How do I preserve the state of the variable viewer in this situation?

Comment: Can you show an example , how exactly are you forming the content of those two jsp's? An also how does the result look like in html.

Comment: I edited it to iframes and not div. We have an external ui where we configure which jsp is to be called for a particular iframe.